# No object detection during training single class

Tags: c, machine-learning, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, yolo

[I'm attaching the screenshot for the same of the result im getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSyb4.png) Im trying to train a single class "drone" in yolo v3 using a dataset of around 2600 images of drones, but during training it is not able to detect the object. Dont know why it shows nan for object all the time even when average loss dropped from 2000 to 0.44(possibly for the no object detection) in about 890 iterations.

Comment: please post your model code

Comment: Hi,
I'm using this repository "https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet"
This is the database im using "https://github.com/chuanenlin/drone-net"

Comment: Did you edit the `*.cfg` file correctly? Also there is a suggestion of training with negative samples.